# Upload Photo with onActivityResult, but without Fullscreen capturing

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to take picture and upload it to server by using onActivityResult, but not by using Fullscreen camera? I just want to use TextureView or SurfaceView for Camera preview and for taking Photo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible. onActivityResult works only with Fullscreen mode.